# (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Managed VMs can not be hosted in the application's region

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, deploying, gcloud-node

I have followed the tutorial https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world (deploying to Google Cloud Platform hello world application on node.js) and after last command:

$ gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --promote

I get:

Copying files to Google Cloud Storage...
Synchronizing files to [gs://staging.first-server-1117.appspot.com/].
Updating module [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Managed VMs can not be hosted in the application's region. (e~) Version: 20151103t135918.388305842753805715

It happens even with unselected timezone.

Why it can happens? Or how it can be fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: Timezone? I assume you created your project in the EU zone, which currently does not support managed VMs "While in Beta, United States only. European Union-hosted applications should not deploy Managed VM modules." (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/). Create another project in the US Zone.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solve problem. I try change timezone in configuration after calling 'gcloud init'. But it didn`t work. New project in US zone is the solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The project was created in the EU zone, which currently does not support managed VMs

> While in Beta, United States only. European Union-hosted applications
>   should not deploy Managed VM modules. (source: [managed vms documenation](http://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms))

The solution is to create a new project in a US Zone. 
Make sure to expand the advanced options during project creation, see the following screenshot:

[image: New Project screen]

Comment: Is it possible to move an existing project from one zone to another?

Comment: @mjs, currently not possible